# Laravel-VueJS specific CSS file for each component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I'm starting a laravel vuejs project, and for the moment I plan to make 1 page = 1 component (time constraint).
I have a lot of css files for each page, and I reduce them with [LaravelMix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix) (Webpack).

When in the component I put `<style scoped>` but I import a css file, it doesn't respect the scope. While when I put raw css, it respects the scope.

Would you have a solution so that I can link a css file (after compilation `laravelmix`) and it can be scoped to the component ?

Thanks in advance,
Feel free to ask if you have any questions,

Kylian

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but not the best

With that :

But this is not the compiled css from webpack in public folder